# Python - webscraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I was trying to do web scraping through Python in Anaconda prompt. Below are the details.

Link for webscraping:

https://sa.aqar.fm/%D9%81%D9%84%D9%84-%D9%84%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B9/1

I am trying to find the title with the below code from the above web link with the below code, but somehow this is giving me an issue.

###Script: for container in containers:

```
title_container = container.findAll("div",{"class":"title"})

title_name = title_container[0].text
```

###Error

> File Webscrap.py, line 75, in

> title_name = title_container[0].text

> IndexError: list index out of range

I have attached the image of the title from the above link which I am supposed to extract.

[image]

Comment: Please provice [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

As the language was a serious barrier for me, I'm still unsure what did I parse actually. However, this should get you there.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://sa.aqar.fm/%D9%81%D9%84%D9%84-%D9%84%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B9/1'

res = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
for items in soup.select(".content [id^='single-id-']"):
    title = items.select_one("h4 a").text
    price = items.select_one(".price").text
    print(title,price)
```